# Forward unanswered calls in Twilio using python

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, call, forward

Has anybody been able to capture the Twilio DialCallStatus? It's referred in many Twilio online documents but I never see one while debugging python scripts. I only see CallStatus such as in the following dump of request.values.

REQUEST VALUES>>> CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('AccountSid', 'ACxxxxxxx'), ('ApiVersion', '2010-04-01'), ('CallSid', 'CA0c9f4e7eb73dfcd72f273451c6aa249c'), ('**CallStatus', 'in-progress**'), ('Called', '+1785xxxxxxx'), ('CalledCity', 'TOPEKA'), ('CalledCountry', 'US'), ('CalledState', 'KS'), ('CalledZip', '66603'), ('Caller', '+1630xxxxxxx'), ('CallerCity', 'ROSELLE'), ('CallerCountry', 'US'), ('CallerState', 'IL'), ('CallerZip', '60193'), ('Digits', '1'), ('Direction', 'inbound'), ('FinishedOnKey', ''), ('From', '+1630xxxxxxx'), ('FromCity', 'ROSELLE'), ('FromCountry', 'US'), ('FromState', 'IL'), ('FromZip', '60193'), ('To', '+1785xxxxxxx'), ('ToCity', 'TOPEKA'), ('ToCountry', 'US'), ('ToState', 'KS'), ('ToZip', '66603'), ('msg', 'Gather End')])])

Actually, I need to forward an unanswered incoming call to another phone number and it seems to be a good time to do that when "no-answer" is reported in call back events. However, at that point, it seems that the call flow has been ended and response.dial.number('next-number') does not work any more.

Has anybody done that in the past?

```
#This is the route where the initial incoming call is answered
@app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  
def gather():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial(timeout=30)
    dial.number(
        '+1-initial-called-number',
        status_callback_event='initiated ringing answered completed busy failed no-answer canceled',
        status_callback='https://my.ngrok.io/response',
        status_callback_method='POST',
    )
    resp.append(dial)
    return str(resp)

@app.route('/response', methods=['POST'])        #This is the call back route
def outbound():
    status=request.values.get('CallStatus', None)
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    if (status=='no-answer'):
        resp.dial(timeout=20).number('+1-next-number')
    return str(resp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I receive a DialCallStatus parameter. This is after a Dial completes and executes the Action url. Here is some Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial action="https:XXXXXX/api/twilio/voice/noanswer" timeout="20">
        <Sip>sip:XXXXXX.sip.us1.twilio.com</Sip>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The https:XXXXXX/api/twilio/voice/noanswer endpoint receives the DialCallCstatus at the completion of the Dial. The Sip part in the example doesn't really matter - the same is true for Number, Client, and Conference actions. Once the Sip, Number, Client, or Conference completes the Dial action URL is called and will have that parameter. The [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) says it is the terminal status for the Dial command.

I do not know Python well but it seems your example code is missing the Action url. Example code from Twilio for Python is in the ["Specify an action URL and method"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial?code-sample=code-specify-an-action-url-and-method&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x)

```
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Dial, VoiceResponse, Say

response = VoiceResponse()
response.dial('415-123-4567', action='/api/twilio/voice/noanswer', method='GET')
response.say('I am unreachable')

print(response)
```

Comment: My code is actually in Python. I see you have Twiml file and PHP file. How do they work together? Also, where is https:XXXXXX/api/twilio/voice/noanswer?

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the example code from PHP to Python (just copy and pasted from Twilio's site). https:XXXXXX/api/twilio/voice/noanswer will be on your web server and you will need to create this (for example https://my.ngrok.io/noanswer). Twilio will send a HTTP Get/Post request to that endpoint at the end of the call which will include a DialCallStatus parameter that you asked about. If you compare your Python code in the Dial section and the code snipped I listed above, you will notice that your code is missing the action attribute.

Comment: I assume that the Twiml portion is in TwiML Bin. Is that right?

Comment: Did you put TwiML portion in TwiML Bin? Do you use Webhook at all? I added action attribute and an '/noanswer' route but it's not hit. I will post the updated code as an answer since it's not easy to post code in this comment box

Comment: Your updated code has the action url in the Number noun, which is the wrong place, the action url needs to be the in the Dial verb. Also, you have the action url as "/handleDialCallStatus" so your url of "/noanswer" will not be reached. You need to combine the Dial with the Number. Put the action url in the same place you have your Timeout=30 (Dial verb). I corrected my proposed answer to us the /noanswer endpoint as the action url in both the Twiml and the Python code. Hope this answer helps! You are close!